# Remove "Pages" from the Url

Tags: publishing-site, public-website, internet-sites

I'm building a public facing SharePoint 2010 site and my client (and i) doesn't like the "/Pages/" part within the Urls that SharePoint generates. Is there a way to take this part out of the Url?

Answer (score 2):

The Pages library is of a special type in SharePoint (template id 850), and most of the Publishing infrastructure is hardwired to it. It is possible to change the path but not without some custom development and tweaking. Removing it completely so that the pages appear to be at the root might not be possible.

Another (probably much simpler) option is to use URL Rewriting to make it appear to users as if pages come from the root, but on the web server they are indeed in /Pages/. I've never tried it myself but it should be possible, with a good set of rewriting rules.

Comment: The rewriting option seems the best one to me! I don't want to mess up SharePoint too much, i just want it to look better :) Does anyone have some examples on how to rewrite within SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

All the publishing pages(that are attached to layout) are stored in Pages library. There is no straight forward way to remove /pages/ from url.

The another option is to move the webparts\content of those pages to webpart pages on the root folder. However, you will loose the features that publishing pages offer.